# Pass input to an application not reading from stdin

Tags: java, linux, windows, command-line-interface

I have an application that reads a text file.

If the application reads it from stdin, then I could forward the input / pipe it

```
$ app < input.txt
$ cat input.txt | app
```

Unfortunately, the application expects a filename as an argument..

```
$ app --input input.txt
```

and I can't easily change the source of input (eg. swap local file [as in example] for a result of a `wget`).

Is there an option to somehow trick this app?

If a solution requires a temporary file, it is necessary that this file is not left on the FS..

*<sub>The app is actually an executable JAR; I'd like the trick to run on Win/Lin..</sub>*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if it could work for you, but I have already solve a similar problem with a fifo.
http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

This could give you the indirection between your app and your source.

```
mkfifo fifo.input
app --input fifo.input
```

Now you can fill the pipe with different sources.

```
cat input > fifo.input
ctrl-c
cat otherInput > fifo.unput
```

Hope it solve your problem on Linux. So far I know it does not exist on Windows.

Comment: this is very nice! Will the `fifo.input` disappear after reading by app?

Comment: No but it take 0 space, the kernel redirect the output to the process directly, no disk space is used. The name on the disk is only an entry point.

Comment: this is very good, if you can pinpoint a way to automatically dispose of whatever is created during this operation (even the hd entry), I can accept right away.

Comment: If you can launch all your operations in a script it is simple, just remove the fifo at the end of the script : rm fifo.input

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this.

```
 java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2
```

where myjar.jar is the executable jar and arg1 arg2 etc are parameters the program expects.

So suppose you want to pass `input.txt` to your application and its the `only commandline parameter required` then command will be

```
java -jar myjar.jar input.txt
```

Comment: How exactly does this read from stdin !? This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: The OP's want to `change the source of input` without creating the file at defualt location with defualt name. if the application uses sdin as input then he had thought of solution as frowarding the input or pipeing. but as he mentions its a executable jar and he was looking for giving the input without creating extra/temp file.

Comment: suppose I don't want to pass an existing file (`input.txt`), but an online resource (like a webpage's html)

Comment: @RoaySpol have you tried creating script with wget to get html save it as temp file pass it to App as commandline parameter and then delete temp generaed file. a small `.sh` Linux or `.bat` windows should serve the perpose.